# Extract string using regex in stored procedure

Tags: regex, database, string, postgresql

I have a regex expression in `javascript` which works fine.

```
var re = /^([0-9]?[A-Z]+?)\s*(?:FM)?[FGHJKMNQUVXZ](?:[02]0)?[12]?[0-9]/i; 
var str = 'RVBM2016';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Now I am trying to reuse the same expression in my stored procedure in `postgres`. Here is how I am trying it:

```
 select regexp_replace('BLM2016', 
       E'/^([0-9]?[A-Z]+?)\s*(?:FM)?[FGHJKMNQUVXZ](?:[02]0)?[12]?[0-9]/i', '', 'g')
```

This should return `BL` only. For `RVBM2016` it should return `RVB` and so on..

But now it has no effect on the input text. Is there any syntactical mistake?

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgresql's regex flavour but as far as I know, the `/pattern/flags` construct is specific to JavaScript. You might want to try with `select regexp_replace('BLM2016', 
       E'^([0-9]?[A-Z]+?)\s*(?:FM)?[FGHJKMNQUVXZ](?:[02]0)?[12]?[0-9]', '', 'gi')` instead

Comment: @Aaron what does `gi` parameter do?

Comment: From your initial try with a 'g' as last parameter, I assumed those were the regex flags. 'g' in this context is 'global', which means that the regex will match as much as possible rather than stopping at the first match

Comment: gi would be global + case-insensitive.

Comment: I just checked the postgresql documentation and the last argument indeed is regex flags. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but according to your javascript code you will want to use `gi` since 1) your JS regex has the `i` flag and 2) your JS code iterates over matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong method to extract string out of expression. The correct version is as follows if anyone is interested:

```
select (regexp_matches('BLM2016', '([0-9]?[A-Z]+?)\s*(?:FM)?[FGHJKMNQUVXZ](?:[02]0)?[12]?[0-9]', 'gi'))[1]
```

Comment: You're missing your initial case-insensitive `i` flag there, but maybe that does not matter.

Comment: @Aaron unfortunately, if I append `i` flag, the expression fails.

Comment: if by appending you mean adding it to the first argument (the regex pattern) that's normal : you should instead add it to the last argument, currently `'g'`, which should become `'gi'`

Comment: I changed `g` to `gi` and now the expression works on case insensitive string. Thank you!